# Programmatic access to the VBA project is not trusted (Option is ticked, Word 2013)

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word, vsto

**Details**

- Add-in type: VSTO (VB.Net)
- Word Version: 2013

**Symptoms**

When i try to inject a VBA module into the user's `Normal.dotm` template during the `Startup` event of the addin I get the `VBA project is not trusted` error even though the option is ticked. It happens when I try to get the VBProject object from the template:

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    Dim template as Word.Template = GetNormalTemplate()
    If template IsNot nothing Then
        Dim vbProj = template.VBProject 'Error thrown here
    End If
End Sub
```

This is only happening when the `General` option `Show the start screen when this application starts` is ticked.

For some reason, even though the normal template is loaded during the *splash* screen, the VBProject is not available on the *start* screen until you are actually displaying a document (blank or otherwise).

**Outcome**

I managed to get what I was aiming for by running the code the first time the `WindowActivate` event fires, instead of during the `Startup` event for the add-in:

```
Property hasInjectedVba As Boolean = False
Private Sub WindowHasActivated() Handles Application.WindowActivate
    If Not hasInjectedVba Then
        Try
            injectVba()
            hasInjectedVba = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            'handle the something that went wrong
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

**Summary**
Cindy makes some very good points if your are trying to do this *securely*, most of all `The security measure not allowing programmatic access to VB projects can remain in-place` if you use an addin template - which avoids the problem altogether.

Comment: It's not quite clear, so double-check: The problem stems from the update, and the fact that "Trust access" isn't staying checked? This is a corporate/network environment? Have you checked with network admin whether a group policy or something like that is enforcing NOT trusting VBA projects? If I were a network admin I'd certainly not allow it - that's a major security breach. Have you considered distributing the VBA code as a VBA template your add-in can load as a "template addin"?

Comment: No, it is staying checked - i had that problem intially, i have checked that there is no GP (Group policy) changing it, there's not. Just before i left work, it *appeared* that i had it narrowed down to users who's word was opening in backstage view (I have mine set to open to a blank document as with previous versions) i am injecting into the normal.dotm too so it might be that it's not loaded at that point but i'm getting the trusted error message.

Comment: Be a good idea to [edit] your question with the new info. And, yes, I suspect that Normal.dotm not being loaded could be an issue. The error might simply be triggered when access is not possible, regardless of why. And I stand by my suggestion of providing an add-in template rather than accessing Normal.dotm through VBE :-)

Comment: Hey Cindy, yeah i just read it back now i'm home and it could do with a rewrite to be honest - i am definitely up for suggestions of other routes, bear with me i will read up when i get home after the gym and update my question - thankyou :)

Comment: No problem - I go off-line for the night soon so won't see anything new for at least 12, maybe 18 hours.

Comment: No prob, well i got it updated before i had to go out - if you want to pop the template idea as an answer, i will try it in the morning and give you the answer if it solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than injecting code into the user's Normal.dotm you should consider creating a template (*.dotm) expressly for the purpose of interacting with your add-in.

Besides COM Add-ins (the technology VSTO leverages) Word also supports "template add-ins". These can be installed in the Word Start-up folder so that Word always loads them automatically OR you can choose to have your add-in load (and unload) it explicitly.

In the Word object model, this is the `Addins` collection. It mirrors the dialog box "Templates and add-ins" in the Word UI.

With the exception of some "Auto" macros, any code (and RibbonXML extensions) in an "add-in template" behaves the same as code in Normal.dotm.

Advantages of using an add-in template instead of Normal.dotm:

- If Normal.dotm is damaged or replaced it doesn't affect your code
- You don't need to have code checking at each start-up whether the modification is present in Normal.dotm and restore it if it's not
- The security measure not allowing programmatic access to VB projects can remain in-place
- You don't have to worry about the notorious "Normal.dotm is locked by another process" which can occur when Word crashes or the user is logged in more than once
- The code is protected from modification by the user
- Easier maintenance if you need to change the code
- Possibly, you could manage with a single, shared template in a network location

Comment: Hey Cindy, oh yeah i know about plenty template addins - the only thing is that i spent a lot of time combining several template addins previously into the single vsto to improve startup performance especially for vpn users, i'm not that worried about inserting/reinserting the module each time if it works as that performed very well. Is there actually a way i can intercept these functions via interop? or do you think  I am going down pretty much the only route available for this?

Comment: Assuming Office 2007 or later your only other option IMO is to "replace" the commands using the RibbonXML (if 2010 or later Ribbon XML can also edit the context menus). But no way to hack keyboard shortcuts except through the Windows API, keyboard shortcuts only "see" VBA. Depends on how your users work? No way to actually hook into these events, however.

Comment: RE start-up performance: Won't be affected if your add-in loads the template instead of putting it in Startup. Might have the same issue as you're having now, though, with timing.